Чем отличаются три вида придаточных: местоименно-определительное, изъяснительное и изъяснительное вмещающее?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Различение этих придаточных — самый сложный вопрос в грамматике СПП. Поэтому важно для одной ситуации составить три разных предложения и сравнить их.
Примечание. Изъяснительное вмещающее СПП — это вариант  изъяснительного СПП с некоторыми признаками местоименной связи. В частности указательное слово там является обязательным,  а опорный глагол не ментального характера, например: заниматься тем, что; состоит в том, что.

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
МОДЕЛИ ТРЕХ ВИДОВ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЙ
Рассмотрим три предложения на одну тему, составленные по разным моделям (похожие примеры даны в учебнике Кустовой):
(1) Изъяснительное придаточное: Петя решил, что нужно отремонтировать велосипед.
(2) Изъяснительное вмещающее придаточное: Весь день Петя занимался тем, что ремонтировал велосипед.
(3) Местоименно-определительное придаточное: Петя занимался тем, что ему нравится. Он ремонтировал велосипед. Петя всегда делает то, что ему нравится.
Есть определенная изъяснительная информация о занятии. Она дается в первых двух предложениях, а в третьем предложении дана ее оценка, характеристика.
Рассмотрим грамматику глаголов в этих примерах. Решить (что?)  — переходный, ментальный, требует обязательного дополнения или придаточного в роли такого дополнения. Заниматься (чем?) — сильное управление, тоже нужно обязательное дополнение в Т.п. или придаточное.
СРАВНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКА ПРИДАТОЧНЫХ
Анализ должен быть комплексным, по всем признакам; но иногда один из признаков позволяет однозначно решить задачу, например союз чтобы (нет такого союзного слова). Вопросы могут быть похожи, но в изъясн. СПП вопрос задается от опорного глагола (что?), а мест.-опред. от указательного местоимения (что именно?).
Местоименно-определительное придаточное:
Есть местоименная пара; указательное местоимение как определяемое слово, его нельзя убрать из главного предложения; союзное слово является членом придаточного предложения (указать каким?), вопрос задается от указательного местоимения: что/чем именно, а глагол управляет местоимением, но не придаточным.
Изъяснительное придаточное:
Указательное слово в главном предложение факультативно, можно обойтись и без него; в придаточном союз или союзное слово; вопрос к придаточному задается от опорного слова (глагола/существительного/наречия) с ментальным значением.
Примечание. Такие предложения называют косвенной речью, в отличие от прямой, и их можно соотнести с БСП (это тоже способ передачи содержания мысли или чувства).
ПРАКТИКА
Ответ  на вопрос по этой теме

Местоименно-определительное придаточное

Я поместил в этой книге только то, что относилось к пребыванию Печорина на Кавказе.
Поместить (что?) — переходный глагол. Это местоименно-определительное придаточное (дается характеристика  сюжетной линии). Важный признак: это не ментальный глагол.
Сравнить  с определительным придаточным: Я поместил в этой книге только те материалы, что (= которые) относилось к пребыванию Печорина на Кавказе.
ПРИЗНАКИ:  местоименная пара то — что; местоимение ТО нельзя убрать из главного предложения; ЧТО является ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ в придаточном; глагол управляет местоимением (поместил что?), а к придаточному задается вопрос от местоимения: что именно?

Изъяснительное придаточное со сходным содержанием.

Я решил, что в книге нужно разместить материалы только о  пребывании Печорина на Кавказе.
Решил (что?) — ментальный опорный глагол со значением желания, воли, усилий, от него задается вопрос к придаточному; указательное слово невозможно; ЧТО — союз, служебное слово перед изъяснительной частью, можно преобразовать в БСП: Я решил: в книге нужно разместить материалы только о  пребывании Печорина на Кавказе.

Попробуем составить вмещающее изъяснительное СПП:

Моя задача состояла в том, чтобы показать характер героя в экстремальных ситуациях на Кавказе.
Глагола состоять — типичный глагол с сильным управлением для таких предложений. Ему обязательно нужно указательное слово (как для мест.-опред. предложений), но при этом в придаточном дается изъяснительная часть, как в обычных изъясн. СПП.
Разбор похожей темы, в том числе  с союзным словом в роли дополнения, можно посмотреть здесь.
Сравним два вида придаточных с местоименной парой то — что:
(1) Я знаю то, что ты еще не успел узнать (местоименно-определительное, характеристика знания). Союзное слово ЧТО в качестве дополнения . Указательное слово обязательно, убрать его нельзя.
(2) Я знаю, что ты еще не успел узнать главного (изъяснительное, содержание знания). Обратим внимание: ЧТО — союз, но не союзное слово/дополнение. Дополнение там уже есть (главного). Указательное слово здесь запрещено (стилистическая ошибка).
